# Regex to identify different forms of year

Tags: python, regex

I am working in Python and need to be able to read a string of text and identify all of the years that are mentioned in the text.

The years would be between 1800 and 2099 and could take on a few different forms:

- `1955`
- `'55`
- `55`

My regex is bad and I need to be careful to avoid matching `19` and then `55`, `195 -> [19]5`, or `20178`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it: `\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2}`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOgGur/2)

**Edit 1:** 
If the regex is used as a validation (rather than an extraction, aka you can assume the only contents of the string will be the number) you could use this `^(\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2})$`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOgGur/3)

**Edit 2:** 
If the regex is used as an extraction you could use this `(?<!\d)(\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2})(?!\d)` however it is allot slower than the before mentioned, since it uses both a look ahead and a look-behind.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOgGur/4)

```
import re

m = re.findall(r"(?<!\d)(\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2})(?!\d)", "1955 '55 55 195 20567")

print(m) # ['1955', "'55", '55']
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, if I add 195 or 20567 this would flag those as well

Comment: @Chris if the regex is used as a validation (rather than an extraction, aka you can assume the only contents of the string will be the number) you could use this `^(\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2})$`

Comment: I wish that was the case.  In my case I am getting passed strings of raw text where year would need to be extracted but that is still useful.

Comment: @Chris in that case you could use this `(?<!\d)(\d{4}|'\d{2}|\d{2})(?!\d)` however it is allot slower than the before mentioned, since it uses both a look ahead and a look-behind. [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOgGur/4)

Comment: This answer would also highlight 1799 which is outside the range mentioned by OP.

Comment: @Gman I understood the question as wanting to match different forms of written dates, and it just so happened to be that in this case the dates would be anything in between  1800 and 2099. However the actual question were how to use "Regex to identify different forms of year".

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

`\b(18|19|20|')?\d\d\b`

the word boundaries `\b` prevent matching substrings or within longer numbers, otherwise we just look for the right century or a single quote (optional), followed by two numbers.

https://regex101.com/r/iggqmK/5/